# X server not working after software update

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I am runing Ubuntu 14.04. I recently did a software update. Now the system does not log into X anymore. After the purple Ubuntu logo screen it goes to a black screen with not blinking cursor.

I did log into recovery and repaired broken packages to no solution.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
Intel corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th gen core processor

$ lshw -C video | grep product
Product: mars [radeo. HD 7670A/8670m/8750m]
Product: Xeon  E3-1200 v3/4th gen core processor
```

The `xorg.0.log` says

```
Data incomplete in file / etc/x11/xorg.conf 
undefined screen nvidia referenced in server layout "layout"
Problem parsing config file
No screens found
```

What could be the solution?